# DEM loses data after clip raster

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-pro, dem, clip

I'm working on a project in ArcGIS Pro in which I need to use DEMs and LiDAR data to estimate tree heights. Unfortunately, some of the DEMs I have to use are at 10-meter resolution, and they cover quite a large area. I have data storage limits I need to work with, so I'm trying to use the clip raster tool to clip the DEM to the size of the tree stand polygon. I've done this with several different areas, and the process has worked out well.

Unfortunately, once I clip the large DEM to the extent of my polygon, the clipped DEM loses all its data. As you can see, I have an original range of values of 180-341 meters, and the output has these crazy float values. Statistics are able to be calculated on the original DEM, but they cannot be determined on the clipped one. Lastly, I can't even find the clipped DEM when I zoom to layer.

What's going on here?

The only thing I've been able to find on Esri's help pages are a similar problem from 2011, but no real solutions were ever offered.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link within your question body to the similar problem that you found.

Comment: Can you edit your question and provide details of the projection/CRS of your raster and vector datasets.

Comment: Similar problem: https://community.esri.com/t5/data-management-questions/missing-data-after-raster-clip/td-p/151527

The rasters and polygons are all of the same projection and coordinate system. Here's my process:

1. Download DEMs and LIDAR data from the USGS Lidar explorer at the highest resolution that ensures complete coverage of the area of interest.
2. Convert the .laz files to .las.
3. Create .las dataset.
4. Convert .las dataset to raster.
5. Mosaic to raster for the DEMs if needed.
6. Ensure projections match the AOI polygons.
7. Clip raster to AOI polygon.
8. Raster calc.

Comment: I just clipped the raster in ArcMap without a problem. It's weird that ArcGIS is having an issue with this...